# What is is the purpose of database-conf.xml and process-conf.xml?

Tags: data-loader

What is is the purpose of database-conf.xml and process-conf.xml and how does the two compare with each other for Salesforce Dataloader?

Answer (score 0):

process-conf.xml contains beans which corresponds to processes which can be invoked from the command line.

Sample process-conf.xml can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/command_line_create_config_file.htm).

Parameters of the bean in process-conf.xml can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=loader_params.htm&type=0).

database-conf.xml is used when the process in process-conf.xml is used to read/write data from/to a relational database using data loader.

Hope this helps.